# Handle different users from file and web-server

Tags: php, nginx, sftp

I have a debian environment with php-fpm running behind nginx as user www-data. I upload files as an other user (user1) account via sftp.

Now I have a problem with permission conflicts, because some files have www-data as owner and some have user1 as owner and I'm wondering how to solve this.

Should I

- create an own php-fpm pool for this user or
- is it possible that users from www-data can access user1 files and vice versa or
- is it possible to automatically change the user of the uploaded files to www-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by sharing same group between those 2 different users. Nginx can be running under a certain user and a group, the directory permissions can spread permissions within that group.

There are many variations. The easiest one is to put user1 into www-data group (assuming www-data user has its own www-data group):

```
useradd -g www-data user1   # make www-data group default for this user
id user1                    # you will see this user has a different default group
```

Keep in mind php and nginx don't need to be configured differently, leave them setup via www-data user.

UPDATE:

**Setuid** can provide same functionality without worrying much of groups for user1. See more details here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setgid

Comment: is it important to use www-data as default group, or should I use `usermod -a -G www-data user1`? I thought, useradd creates a new user

Comment: As SSH (sftp), Nginx and PHP-FPM are all running under same www-data group (different users don't matter) an access is going to be shared. If you user1 will have another default group, files created (copied via SSH) will have different group permissions. BUT **setuid** can do the same without worrying of groups